# Win32 exception is being thrown while taking a screenshot [c#]

Tags: c#, exception, screen, screenshot

My application is recording the screen (taking screenshots) using Graphics.CopyFromScreen(...) function. The problem is that sometimes an ,,Invalid handle win32" exception is being thrown for some unknown reason. The program is running in the background (it's a console app project with hidden console). I was looking for a solution with google, but I haven't found anything helpful in my case.

The function I wrote:

```
    static Bitmap takeScreenshot()
    {
        Bitmap bmpScreenCapture = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenCapture))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                0, 0,
                                bmpScreenCapture.Size,
                                CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        }
        return bmpScreenCapture;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message..?

Comment: How? Visual Studio just shows a yellow box with ,,Ivalid handle" information. I can't even show InnerException of this exception cause a next error is showing up... It's a very weird problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out that the app was trying to create files that already existed. Somehow that caused an exception, but I don't know why. I deleted old files and now program seems to work properly...